# Manipulacion de imagen respecto a su id con jquery y json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables, imagen

Estoy haciendo un tabla con DataTables para mostrar lo que tengo en la base de datos, es una pagina para un concurso para escoger un dibujo mas interesante, cuando llenan el formulario pido:

1. Correo(ID).
2. Nombre.
3. Nombre de su personaje.
4. El por que del nombre del personaje.
5. El archivo en formato jpg, png.
6. Y la descripción del dibujo.

Quiero hacer el trabajo fácil para el administrador haciendo una tabla que muestre todos los datos de las personas que han participado mostrando los datos anteriores, pero quiero que en el atributo del archivo aparezca la imagen dependiendo y correspondiendo de cada usuario con su Correo(ID), y no eh encontrado la forma.
En la tabla de mi base de datos tengo guardado solo el nombre del archivo, y en mi servidor tengo un archivo llamado files donde se guardan todas las imágenes.

Este es mi cogido javascript y html, si me pudieran orientar se los agradecería.**

```js
$(function() {
    var row = "";
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "php/read.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            if(response) {
                for(i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                    row +=  '<tr data-id="' + response[i]["Correo"] + '">';
                    row +=      '<td>' + response[i]["Correo"] + '</td>';
                    row +=      '<td>' + response[i]["Nombre"] + '</td>';
                    row +=      '<td>' + response[i]["NombreAgui"] + '</td>';
                    row +=      '<td>' + response[i]["DescNom"]+ '</td>';
                    row +=      '<td>' + response[i]["ArchDib"]+ '</td>';
                    row +=      '<td>' + response[i]["DescDib"]+ '</td>';
                    row +=      '<td>' + '<img src="files/pepe.jpg" class=img-fluid">' + '</td>';
                }
            }
            $("#tablas tbody").append(row);
            $(document).ready( function () {
                $('#tablas').DataTable();
                        } );
            $("#tablas").DataTable({
                retrieve: true,
                dom: "Bfrtip",
                "language": {
                    "lengthMenu": "Muestra _MENU_ entradas",
                    "zeroRecords": "No existe información.",
                    "info": "Muestra _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
                    "infoEmpty": "No hay registros disponibles.",
                    "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado por _MAX_ registros)",
                    "search": "Buscar:",
                    "paginate": {
                        "previous": "Anterior",
                        "next": "Siguiente"
                    }
                },
                "order": []
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
            <div  class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <table id="tablas">
                     <thead>
                      <th>Correo</th>
                      <th>Nombre</th>
                      <th>Nombre del personaje</th>
                      <th>Desc.del Nombre</th>
                      <th>Dibujo</th>
                      <th>Desc.del Dibujos</th>
                      <th>Edicion</th>
                     </thead>
                     <tbody></tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div> 
  </div>
```

Comment: tu carpeta files esta en el mismo directorio donde ejecutas la funcion?

Comment: ¿El problema cuál es? En el código veo que pones un archivo `pepe.jpg` a mano?

Comment: sI @IgmerRodriquez

Comment: me gustiaria que en la columna de dibujo salieran la imagen que esta adentro de una carpeta llamada files, con su respectivo id que en este caso es correo, es para visualizar la imagen que subio cada participante.

Comment: row +=      '<td>' + response[i]["ArchDib"]+ '<img src="files/"llamar a cada archivo respecto a su id" class="img-fluid">' + '</td>';    quiero concatenar el nombre del archivo con la imagen para que en la tabla salga la imagen con el archivo pero me sale error.

Comment: ya encontre la solucion que es la siguiente: row +=      '<td><img src="/micrositios/ku/files/'+response[i]['ArchDib']+'"></td>';